# align inside of tabular

Tags: tables, align

Today I failed using an `align`-environment inside of a `tabular`-environment.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
      A & B \\%
      & %
\begin{align}
    A &= B \\
    C &= D
\end{align}%
      \\%
    \end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

When I try this I'll get an error claiming: "Argument of \align has an extra }." and "Paragraph ended before \align was complete." and much more.

When I enclose everything in paraphrases (like `{\begin{align}.....\end{align}}`) I'll get some other errors: "Missing \endgroup inserted." and multiple "Missing } inserted."

**How can I use the `align`-environment properly inside of a table?**

Comment: It should look like: A  |  B \\ (blank)  |  (equation) \\

Comment: You should use the `aligned` environment here.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> When I enclose everything in paraphrases (like `{\begin{align}.....\end{align}}`) I'll get some other errors: "Missing \endgroup inserted." and multiple "Missing } inserted."

It works alright in the following examples.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|}
      A & B \\
        & {$\!\begin{aligned} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482/16595 
               A &= B \\    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78788/16595
               C &= D \end{aligned}$}
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabular}{l|p{5cm}|}
      A & B \\
        & {\begin{align}
               A &= B \\
               C &= D \end{align}}
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|X|}
      A & B \\
        & {\begin{align}
               A &= B \\
               C &= D \end{align}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2009-April/012236.html

Comment: This is working, but I get no tags (the equations are not numbered).

Comment: @DL6ER The `align` environment does need a line width (it stretches). So you’ll want to use a `p` column or something with the `X` column of `tabularx`.

Comment: So what was the solution here? Just to use tabularx instead of tabular?

Comment: I get errors while running your code! :(

Comment: @H.R. Someone [ate my backslashes](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/7168/16595). It should work now.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to tabular is cals tables:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cals}
\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{10mm}{40mm}}
\brow
\cell{A}
\cell{B}
\erow
\brow
\cell{}
\cell{
  \begin{align}
      A &= B \\
      C &= D
  \end{align}%
}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```