# Misplaced \omit when adding align* within tabularx

Tags: align, tabularx

I am trying to provide a summary and associate a symbol with the equations that define it. To achieve this goal, I tried using a `tabularx` and within the `tabularx` place `align*` environments to provide the definition. I've seen this is possible here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121409/70681

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c X}
\makecell{$\compilerenv$ \\ Environment compile \\ function} & {\begin{align*}
    A &= B \\
    A &= C \end{align*}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
```

`makecell` is a command defined as `\newcommand{\makecell}[2][@{}c@{}]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}`.

I tried compiling the code without the `align*` column (replaced it with a single letter) and it worked.

The error I get is:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\math@cr@@@ ...@ \@ne \add@amps \maxfields@ \omit
                                              \kern -\alignsep@ \iftag@ ...
l.10 \end{tabularx}

! Misplaced \omit.
\math@cr@@@ ...@ \@ne \add@amps \maxfields@ \omit
                                              \kern -\alignsep@ \iftag@ ...
l.10 \end{tabularx}
```

repeated a number of times.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$`?

Comment: @Bernard `aligned` works. Thank you so much! Would you mind making this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry! I'll do that from my next question. I didn't post on TexExchange much and while I read a lot, I always took the fact that there's a whole document posted for granted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the place of the `align*` environment, this should work (you can add the `\displaystyle` directive if necessary):

```
$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$
```

Comment: If this answer was helpful, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635159/214194) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I get no error from your input, but not an exciting result either:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}

\newcommand{\makecell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\compilerenv}{???}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c X}
\hline
\makecell{$\compilerenv$ \\ Environment compile \\ function} &
  {\begin{align*}
    A &= B \\
    A &= C \end{align*}}\\
\hline
\makecell{$\compilerenv$ \\ Environment compile \\ function} &
\centering\arraybackslash
$\begin{aligned}
    A &= B \\
    A &= C \end{aligned}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

A better result is obtained with `\centering` and `aligned`, as you see in the bottom part (I used rules just to have a better look at the involved spaces).

[image]