# How can I align math in table across regular and multirow cells?

Tags: tables, math-mode, align, multirow

I'm trying to create a table with math that is properly aligned horizontally but can also be centred across multiple rows. I've tried two different methods (one using a solution from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78839/126070)) and both result in slight alignment errors, as shown.

[image: Output of MWE]

I've previously tried using an `aligned` environment as in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78788/align-equations-over-multiple-tabular-rows) but as far as I can tell there is no way to align math across multiple such environments or insert a `cmidrule` into one.

Is there a way to modify either of these solutions to fix the errors shown? What's the best solution to align math in this way?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78788/align-equations-over-multiple-tabular-rows/78839#78839
\newcolumntype{A}{ >{$} r <{$} @{} >{${}} l <{$} } % A for "align"

\begin{document}

%   FIXED COLUMN DIVIDER
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Fixed column divider}
    \begin{tabular}{ l r@{ = } l r@{ $\leftarrow$ } l }
        \toprule
        \textbf{Name}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Math}}   
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{More Math}}      \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Foo}
        &   $A$
        &   $x^2 + y^3$
        &   $x$
        &   $x(1 - \alpha)$                         \\
        &   $BC$
        &   $x^3 - y^2$         
        &   $y$
        &   $y(1 + \beta)$                          \\
        \cmidrule{4-5}
        \multirow{2}{*}{Bar}
        &   $D$
        &   $xy + w_z$
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{$w_z$}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{$w_z(1 + q)$}           \\  
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{Note: if $A > D \text{ then } D \leftarrow AB + C$}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{}                    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}

%   NEW COLUMN TYPE
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{New column type}
    \begin{tabular}{ l A A }
        \toprule
        \textbf{Name}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Math}}   
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{More Math}}      \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Foo}
        &   A   &= x^2 + y^3
        &   x   &\leftarrow x(1 - \alpha)           \\
        &   BC  &= x^3 - y^2            
        &   y   &\leftarrow y(1 + \beta)            \\
        \cmidrule{4-5}
        \multirow{2}{*}{Bar}
        &   D   &= xy + w_z
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{$w_z$}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{$\leftarrow w_z(1 + q)$}\\  
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{Note: if $A > D \text{ then } D \leftarrow AB + C$}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{}                    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I take it you want $w_z$ aligned with Bar to the left and $x$ above?

Comment: Correct! Specifically, the `leftarrow`s in the $w_z$ side of the table should be aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the LHS of each equation inside a box that's measurable and then adjust it so that all those in the second [third] column have the same-width LHS. This approach is made easy using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) which uses a `\label`-`\ref`-like approach to store the maximum box width (requires two compilation on the first go or any subsequent changes).

[`\eqmathbox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764) is similar to `\eqparbox`, retaining the math context. The syntax `\eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` aligns `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` based on the preferred `<align>`ment specified. This is ultimately done where `<stuff>` is placed inside a box of maximum width across all `<stuff>`s with the same `<tag>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,booktabs,xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{l} }
  \toprule
  \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Math} & \textbf{More Math} \\
  \midrule
  \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Foo} &
    $\eqmathbox[L][r]{A} = x^2 + y^3$ &
    $\eqmathbox[R][r]{x} \leftarrow x (1 - \alpha)$ \\
  &
    $\eqmathbox[L][r]{BC} = x^3 - y^2$ &
    $ \eqmathbox[R][r]{y} \leftarrow y (1 + \beta)$ \\
  \cmidrule{3-3}
  \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Bar} &
    $ \eqmathbox[L][r]{D} = x y + w_z$ &
    \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
      $\eqmathbox[R][r]{w_z} \leftarrow w_z (1 + q)$%
    } \\
  & Note: if $A > D$ then $D \leftarrow AB + C$ \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Above I used `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{<stuff>}` in lieu of `\multirow` since it's not really part of the question, nor needed.

Comment: This works great, thanks! Replacing `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{<stuff>}` with `\multirow{2}{*}{<stuff>}` appears to allow me to easily modify the solution to vertically center over _n_ rows. Is there a reason I should be preferring `\raisebox`?

Comment: @TACD: No; [`multirow`](//ctan.org/pkg/multirow) is just another package dependency that is not always needed.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure it would work, but you can put `\multirow` inside a `\multicolumn` (just like `\raisebox`) and let it compute the offsets.

Note the phantom entries (including a phantom `\leftarrow`) in the last line to set up the alignment.  Both cells are the widest for any row, so placement of the `\multicolumn` version is simple.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}

%   FIXED COLUMN DIVIDER
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Fixed column divider}
    \begin{tabular}{ l r@{ = } l r@{ $\leftarrow$ } l }
        \toprule
        \textbf{Name}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Math}}   
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{More Math}}      \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Foo}
        &   $A$
        &   $x^2 + y^3$
        &   $x$
        &   $x(1 - \alpha)$                         \\
        &   $BC$
        &   $x^3 - y^2$         
        &   $y$
        &   $y(1 + \beta)$                          \\
        \cmidrule{4-5}
        \multirow{2}{*}{Bar}
        &   $D$
        &   $xy + w_z$
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$w_z \leftarrow w_z(1 + q)$}}\\
        &   \multicolumn{2}{l}{Note: if $A > D \text{ then } D \leftarrow AB + C$}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{r@{ \phantom{$\leftarrow$} }}{\phantom{$w_z$}}% remove \leftarrowy
        &   \phantom{$w_z(1 + q)$}\\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This works well, but it's not immediately obvious (to me at least) how to modify this for proper vertical alignment over _n_ rows.

Comment: Note revised solution.  This would have been slightly easier if you had not automated the \leftarrow.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It is better to use math environments directly rather than adjust column properties. You may have noticed that in align environments, the spacing between entries is large for a table. In this case you can use `\\[-1.5mm]` just to reduce the spacing. You can replace 1.5 with whatever number you want, , but you must always be sure not to separate `\\` from `[-1.5mm]`.

The `>{\hsize=scale\hsize}` specification in `tabularx` environment can be used to specify the column width in terms of another, a very desirable feature. For instance, in the table above, the second row is set to be 70% larger than the third one. Here is the source code for the table shown above:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\renewcommand \tabularxcolumn [1] { >{ \centering } m{#1} }
\newcommand {\scalelinespace} [1] {\rule{0pt}{#1\normalbaselineskip}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[h]


    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}C| >{\hsize=1.45\hsize}C| >{\hsize=1.05\hsize}C}

        \toprule

        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Math} & \textbf{More Math} \\

        \midrule

        Foo
        & 
            $\begin{aligned}
                A &= x^{2} + y^{3} \\[-1.5mm]
                BC &= x^{3} - y^{2}
            \end{aligned}$
        &
            $\begin{aligned}
            x &\leftarrow x \thinspace (1 - \alpha)  \\[-1.5mm]
            y &\leftarrow y \thinspace (1 + \beta) 
            \end{aligned}$
        \\
        \Xcline{3-3}{0.2mm}
        \scalelinespace{1}
        Bar
        & 
        \scalelinespace{1}
            \hspace{4.1mm} $D = x y + w_{z}$
            \text{Note if } $A>D \text{ then } D \leftarrow AB+C$
        &
        \scalelinespace{1}
            $w_{z} \leftarrow w_{z} \thinspace (1 + q)$
        \\ 
        \bottomrule

    \end{tabularx}

\end{table*}




\end{document}
```

Comment: I apologise if my question was unclear — I'm not trying to align the math in each column horizontally, I'm trying to keep it left-justified but aligned with the primary math operator (so `=` for the second column and `\leftarrow` for the third).